# Markdown to LaTeX in Python

Tags: python, latex, markdown

There are few versions of the Markdown-Latex package for Python, but I can't get any to work with the current version of the Markdown package.  Does anyone have a working example using python like:

```
lines = markdown.markdown(lines,extensions=[MarkdownLatex()]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What package? Can you provide a link and a bit more context for that code?

Answer (score 2):

You can rename the file of the extension to "mdx_latex.py" and then, in the same directory, you can run the following command:

```
import markdown
md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=['latex'])
out = md.convert(text)
```

Comment: This solution no longer works. The 2nd line gives the error `AttributeError: Failed to initiate extension 'latex': module 'latex' has no attribute 'makeExtension'`